# Android - OnMyLocationChangeListener not work when I close and open again the activity

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, locationlistener

In my application I'm using Maps API v2.
I have an activity that contains a map:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

When the activity starts, shows my location on the map and is updated using OnMyLocationChangeListener.
Everything works perfectly, but I have a big problem:

When I open the activity works great, I can see the icon of the location in the notification bar
[image]

If I push the home button (the square button) of the device, I leave the app, but not close it.
When I reopen my application, continues showing and updating my location on the map
this is correct, now comes the problem.

When i push the device´s back button, i leave the app, but when I open it again, the location is no longer active (the location icon is not shown in the notification bar) and the map is not updated

I have tried many ways to do it, I read forums and tutorials, but without success.
I do not know what is the problem.

I appreciate the help, I am very confused.

Thank you very much.

This is the code of my activity:

public class Home extends ActionBarActivity {

```
        public static GoogleMap mMap;

        //...

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }       

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                if (ll_ubicacion_mapa.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    ll_ubicacion_mapa.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                }

                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16.0f));

                try {
                    indicadorDePosicion.remove();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                indicadorDePosicion = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .flat(true)
                        .title(getResources().getString(R.string.TXestasAqui))
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                        .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));

            }
        };

        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);
    }


      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        //...
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();


    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Comment: It´s in portrait mode forced

Comment: the problem is in the use of "static" for the GoogleMap object.
You should not use static since when you click back and open the app again, mMap is not null but the activity is recreated and the map comes from a new context, hence is not the same you were holding with static.

You can fix it by removing the static or remove the pointer when your activity calls onDestroy ("mMap = null")

Comment: I remove removed the pointer when your activity calls onDestroy (set mMap=null) .but when I click back in divice and reopen my app, method OnMyLocationChangeListener does't work ! Please help me